# How can I call a function from another file without importing the main file?

Tags: python, python-3.x, import, module

I want to know how to call a function for my GUI project. This is my main.py file in which there is a `set_name` function that I want to call. For example: `a=Thread(target='set_name')`

Which call `set_name` function when start function is used to start it.

```
from tkinter import *
import set_item
root=Tk()
def set_cordinate (event,A):
    set_item.Sett.set_name(A)
def get_cordinate(t):
    print(t)
b=Button(root,text='Hi',border=0,command=lambda:set.Set.call_modify('Button b clicked')).pack
co=Button(root,text='Get cordinates',command=lambda=set_cordinate((100,200)))
```

And this is set_item.py

```
from tkinter import *
root=Tk()
class Sett:
    def __init__(self):
        ...
    def set_cordinate(self,ele):
        e=Button(root,text='Get cordinates').pack()
        e.bind('<Button-3>',??)#Here I should call get_cordinate of main.py file and pass ele into it.
        #Instead of ?? what should I write can anybody please tell me             
    def call_modify(self,name):
        ...
```

Comment: How you access the module without import?

Comment: Don't know but threading module's Thread class does it,so I thought we can do it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you read the python docs on modules? If not then I think you should check it out once :-), I think it will help you!
[Python Modules docs](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html)

Comment: @levers You're most welcome! I'm glad that it helped you!!!